# Two goroutine in the same Channel - how are they executed?

Tags: go, goroutine

When I take the tour of Golang from golang.org, there's one code snippet I don't understand:

```
func sum(a []int, c chan int, order int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range a {
        sum += v
    }
    fmt.Println(order, a)
    c <- sum // 将和送入 c
}

func main() {
    a := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    a1, a2 := a[:len(a)/2], a[len(a)/2:]

    go sum(a1, c, 1)
    x := <-c
    go sum(a2, c, 2)
    y := <-c
    //x := <-c
    //y := <-c
    // x, y := <-c, <-c // 从 c 中获取

    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

**This is the output I expected:**

```
1 [7 2 8]
2 [-9 4 0]
17 -5 12
```

and when I changed the code:

```
func main() {
    a := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    a1, a2 := a[:len(a)/2], a[len(a)/2:]

    go sum(a1, c, 1)
    //x := <-c
    go sum(a2, c, 2)
    //y := <-c
    x := <-c
    y := <-c
    // x, y := <-c, <-c // 从 c 中获取

    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

**Why is the output like this:**

```
2 [-9 4 0] 
1 [7 2 8]
-5 17 12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the thing is u've missed the concept of concurrency
there is no guarantee in executing functions in exact order of calling them with go

the reason first code snippet works orderly is the `x := <-c` part
this line force your app to wait until c channel is filled with data so second goroutine wont be called

Comment: yes, but online Playground always run 2rd before 1st,make me confuse,and i run it locally two goroutines go randomly

Answer (score 0):

let me help you with that.

in your second scenario:

```
2 [-9 4 0] 
1 [7 2 8]
-5 17 12
```

As you can see second goroutine executes faster than first one and in result we have x = result of second goroutine (-5).

When you do run function/method with **go** keyword it runs in concurrency which means main function doesn't wait it execution (if do not use **sync.WaitGroup{}** or **select{}**).

you can find more details from docs:
https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup

Comment: channel doc says it blocked when there is no receiver. in this case  the statement **fmt.Println(order, a)** is before channel send. the first goroutine is blocked after print statement , is it right?

Comment: is it run goroutine randomly in the same scope? or i can't understand why the 2rd is exec before 1st

Comment: Goroutines go parallel (or we could think that) - that means it is no guarantee whether routine 1 or 2 finish first. Only synchronization points are sending/receiving from channels, but no one could said whether first g1 or g2 tries send result to channel c.

Comment: shx, if you used javaScript so it's like ajax request. You can make multiple ajax requests but you don't know which return result first.